# Change name of component menu

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I'd like to change the name of my component menu item. I took a screenshot, this is the place where i want a different name for my component.

[image: Menu]

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own to try and figure it out? Out of all honest, it's a rather pointless thing to do. It's not as if it's a fundamental bit of text available to the public.

Comment: Why ? In my case, there is a name of my component without spaces, something like "mycomponentname", i simply want a normal name...

Comment: Do you have language debugging turned on? Have you checked the files to make sure hte translation is there?

Answer (score 2):

To adding menu item for your custom component you can follow this link to add custom component menu item. Here the link:

[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part)

In the default.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE"> <--The title which you defined in component language file will be shown here or Simply you can directly put name in the title-->
                <message>
                        <![CDATA[COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
                </message>
        </layout>
</metadata>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm asking how to change name of the component - not the name of menu item.

Comment: what do you mean by changing the component name..Have you tried above thing it will display the name whatever you put in the title. In the above image you put change me..if you put change me on the title then it will be display over the menu item..Hope you will understand.